# When I'm using Redirect from react-router-dom, I'm getting the TypeError: func.apply is not a function. I'm new to react and redux

Tags: redirect, react-redux, react-router-dom

```
try {
    s_product = await product.save();
    res.json(s_product);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
}
```

Error code:

```
TypeError: func.apply is not a function
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
node_
```

modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:337

```
  334 |     window.event = windowEvent;
  335 |   }
  336 | 
> 337 |   func.apply(context, funcArgs);
      | ^  338 |   didError = false;
  339 | } // Create a global error event handler. We use this to capture the value
  340 | // that was thrown. It's possible that this error handler will fire more
```

Any help really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this out on w3 schools [link to the page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp),
these kind of errors generally occur when your function is not defined
in the expected way

[image: The expected way]

The site says that you should pass arguments as an array.
Check that, as your code doesn't really give much information about that if you are passing arguments as array or not